# Show the row of the best result compared to the previous year

Tags: sql-server

First thanks for your time and I am using SQL Server

Hello, I am having a problem obtaining the data, first I will explain the case.

I have a data set that contains rows from both the current year and the previous year (2022, 2021), these have a type, result and passport of the related person.

It is necessary to compare the same person for his passport in these two years.

What is required is to get the row with the best result in the same type in the last year example:

I have this case

```sql
('ecu123453', 'speed', 12, '2021-05-05'),
('ecu123453', 'speed', 11, '2022-07-11'),
```

For the speed type, the best time is the smallest value, that is, in this case it is true that in the current year the user with passport ecu123453 improved his time, therefore it is shown

```sql
('ecu123453', 'speed', 11, '2022-07-11')
```

In case it was the other way around:

I have this case

```sql
('ecu123453', 'speed', 11, '2021-05-05'),
('ecu123453', 'speed', 12, '2022-07-11'),`
```

So in the current year, he did not improve his mark, so the value is not shown.

So, I have the different ones: types, disc, speed, medium distance, fondo, javelin

For the types that are related to careers:
speed, medium distance, fondo, the one with the least time is considered the best time

While those that are launch:
disc, javelin throw, is considered the best throw that has the highest value.

I have an example mounted where it can be tested.
https://dbfiddle.uk/z_ap5q0r

```sql
CREATE TABLE data
(
    passport varchar(9),
    type      varchar(50),
    result    int,
    fecha     datetime
);
INSERT INTO data(passport, type, result, fecha)
VALUES ('ecu123451', 'disc', 60, '2021-05-03'),
       ('ecu123451', 'disc', 50, '2022-02-20'),
       ('ecu123452', 'velocidad', 12, '2022-02-23'),
       ('ecu123452', 'jump', 11, '2021-05-04'),
       ('ecu123453', 'velocidad', 12, '2021-05-05'),
       ('ecu123453', 'velocidad', 11, '2022-07-11'),
       ('uru123454', 'media distancia', 150, '2022-02-24'),
       ('uru123454', 'jump', 10, '2021-05-04'),
       ('uru123454', 'media distancia', 110, '2021-05-09'),
       ('uru123455', 'jump', 7, '2022-02-19'),
       ('uru123455', 'velocidad', 9, '2022-02-23'),
       ('uru123455', 'fondo', 250, '2022-02-25'),
       ('uru123455', 'disc', 60, '2021-05-05'),
       ('uru123455', 'fondo', 250, '2021-05-10'),
       ('uru123456', 'disc', 40, '2022-02-20'),
       ('per123457', 'jump', 9, '2022-02-19'),
       ('per123457', 'disc', 45, '2021-05-05'),
       ('per123458', 'disc', 45, '2022-02-20'),
       ('per123459', 'jump', 6, '2021-05-04'),
       ('per123459', 'velocidad', 12, '2021-05-08'),
       ('arg123460', 'jump', 8, '2022-02-19'),
       ('arg123460', 'jump', 9, '2021-05-04'),
       ('arg123460', 'velocidad', 10, '2021-05-08'),
       ('arg123462', 'velocidad', 10, '2022-02-23'),
       ('arg123462', 'disc', 38, '2021-05-05'),
       ('arg123462', 'lanza jabalina', 55, '2021-05-07'),
       ('col123463', 'lanza jabalina', 40, '2022-02-22'),
       ('col123463', 'velocidad', 13, '2021-05-08'),
       ('col123464', 'disc', 35, '2022-02-20'),
       ('col123464', 'velocidad', 11, '2022-02-23'),
       ('col123465', 'jump', 7, '2021-05-04'),
       ('col123465', 'disc', 35, '2021-05-05');
```

I have been trying to get this data without much luck, does anyone have any idea how it can be done

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this? (not sure how it will perform on more data).

```
WITH best_results_max
AS (SELECT
             MAX(result) AS best_result,
             passport,
             type
    FROM     data AS d
    WHERE    d.type IN ( 'disc', 'javelin throw' ) /*determine which types highest are best result*/
    GROUP BY d.passport,
             d.type
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
             MIN(result) AS best_result,
             passport,
             type
    FROM     data AS d
    WHERE    d.type IN ( 'speed', 'medium distance', 'fondo' ) /*determine which types lowest are best result*/
    GROUP BY d.passport,
             d.type)
SELECT d.*
FROM   best_results_max AS b
       JOIN data AS d ON d.passport = b.passport
                         AND d.type = b.type
                         AND b.best_result = d.result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the previous value with "lag" and compare it with "case when".

Please review the example.

```
select
* 
,LAG(d.result) OVER (partition BY d.passport,d.type ORDER BY d.passport,d.type) as 'prevResult'

,(case 
  when 
     d.type in ('types', 'disc', 'speed', 'medium distance', 'fondo', 'javelin','velocidad')
    and d.result < (LAG(d.result) OVER (partition BY d.passport,d.type ORDER BY d.passport,d.type))
  then 'good' 

  when 
     d.type in ('other')
    and d.result > (LAG(d.result) OVER (partition BY d.passport,d.type ORDER BY d.passport,d.type))
  then 'good' 

  
  else 'bad' end
  ) as 'isGood'

from data d
```

| passport | type | result | fecha | prevResult | isGood |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| arg123460 | jump | 8 | 2022-02-19 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| arg123460 | jump | 9 | 2021-05-04 00:00:00.000 | 8 | bad |
| arg123460 | velocidad | 10 | 2021-05-08 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| arg123462 | disc | 38 | 2021-05-05 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| arg123462 | lanza jabalina | 55 | 2021-05-07 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| arg123462 | velocidad | 10 | 2022-02-23 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| col123463 | lanza jabalina | 40 | 2022-02-22 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| col123463 | velocidad | 13 | 2021-05-08 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| col123464 | disc | 35 | 2022-02-20 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| col123464 | velocidad | 11 | 2022-02-23 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| col123465 | disc | 35 | 2021-05-05 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| col123465 | jump | 7 | 2021-05-04 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| ecu123451 | disc | 60 | 2021-05-03 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| ecu123451 | disc | 50 | 2022-02-20 00:00:00.000 | 60 | good |
| ecu123452 | jump | 11 | 2021-05-04 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| ecu123452 | velocidad | 12 | 2022-02-23 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| ecu123453 | velocidad | 12 | 2021-05-05 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| ecu123453 | velocidad | 11 | 2022-07-11 00:00:00.000 | 12 | good |
| per123457 | disc | 45 | 2021-05-05 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| per123457 | jump | 9 | 2022-02-19 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| per123458 | disc | 45 | 2022-02-20 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| per123459 | jump | 6 | 2021-05-04 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| per123459 | velocidad | 12 | 2021-05-08 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| uru123454 | jump | 10 | 2021-05-04 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| uru123454 | media distancia | 110 | 2021-05-09 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| uru123454 | media distancia | 150 | 2022-02-24 00:00:00.000 | 110 | bad |
| uru123455 | disc | 60 | 2021-05-05 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| uru123455 | fondo | 250 | 2021-05-10 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| uru123455 | fondo | 250 | 2022-02-25 00:00:00.000 | 250 | bad |
| uru123455 | jump | 7 | 2022-02-19 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| uru123455 | velocidad | 9 | 2022-02-23 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |
| uru123456 | disc | 40 | 2022-02-20 00:00:00.000 | *null* | bad |

```
select * from (
select
* 
,LAG(d.result) OVER (partition BY d.passport,d.type ORDER BY d.passport,d.type) as 'prevResult'

,(case 
  when 
     d.type in ('types', 'disc', 'speed', 'medium distance', 'fondo', 'javelin','velocidad')
    and d.result < (LAG(d.result) OVER (partition BY d.passport,d.type ORDER BY d.passport,d.type))
  then 'good' 

  when 
     d.type in ('other')
    and d.result > (LAG(d.result) OVER (partition BY d.passport,d.type ORDER BY d.passport,d.type))
  then 'good' 

  
  else 'bad' end
  ) as 'isGood'

from data d
  ) t 
where t.isGood='good'
```

| passport | type | result | fecha | prevResult | isGood |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ecu123451 | disc | 50 | 2022-02-20 00:00:00.000 | 60 | good |
| ecu123453 | velocidad | 11 | 2022-07-11 00:00:00.000 | 12 | good |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aG9tL50Y)

Comment: Very close, but what I don't see is for example in the case of jumping

only the best (biggest) jump should be shown only if in the current year it is better than the previous year.

For example for ('arg123460', 'jump', 8, '2022-02-19'),
       ('arg123460', 'jump', 9, '2021-05-04'),
 although 9 is bigger, but it happened the previous year, it should only be shown if the mark is improved in the current year